# How to join two LinestringM into one without dropping M value?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have, for example, two Linestrings with M value:
`LINESTRINGM(1 0 2, 2 0 4, 4 0 7)`
and
`LINESTRINGM(4 0 7, 6 0 9, 10 0 10)`

How can I merge them into one Linestring and preserve the M value?

Expected result: `LINESTRINGM(1 0 2, 2 0 4, 4 0 7, 6 0 9, 10 0 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pretty tough problem, because the GEOS library underneath PostGIS does not preserve M values. It does preserve Z values though, so if you can transfer your M to the Z, you can pass them through. You might have to dump points from the line, set the Z, and then makeline on them to do so. Ugly, but practical.